# Using Moq callbacks from a helper class for Prism IEventAggregator

Tags: c#, moq, prism, mstest, eventaggregator

I'm trying to build a helper class to help with mocking prisms EventAggregator, mostly because I don't want to have to copy / paste the same large mock setup in multiple places.

What I have at the moment is as follows.  (apologies, had to hand copy the code over so there may be a couple mistakes)

```
public Mock<IEventAggregator> CreateEventAggregator()
{
  return new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
}

public Mock<TEventType> CreateEvent<TEventType, T>(Mock<IEventAggregator> eventAggregator)
  where TEventType : PubSubEvent<T>, nuew()
{
  var mockEvent = new Mock<TEventType>();
  evengAggregator.Setup(e => e.GetEvent<TEventType>()).Returns(mockEvent.Object);

  return mockEvent;
}

public void SetupEventCallback<T, TEventType>(Mock<TEventType> mockEvent)
    where TEventType : PubSubEvent<string>
{
  Action<T> callback = null;
  mockEvent.Setup( p =>
  p.Subscribe( It.IsAny<Action<T>>(),
  It.IsAny<ThreadOption>(),
  It.IsAny<bool>(),
  It.IsAny<Predicate<T>>()))
    .Callback<Action<T>, ThreadOption, bool, Predicate<T>>((e, t, b, a) => callback = e);
  return callback;
}
```

The problem I'm seeing presents in SetupEventCallback.

If I have this exact code in my test method constructor (with string in place of T), when the callback is used, the test passes.  However, when I access it through the helper method, callback remains null.

I've tried hardcoding the helper method to use string instead of T but had the same result.

```
[TestClass]
public TestClassConstructor
{
  helper = EventAggregatorTesthelper();
  _mockEventAggregator = helper.CreateEventAggregator();
  _mockEvent = helper.CreateEvent<MyPubsubEvent>()

  //Doesn't Work
  callback = helper.CreateEventCallback<string, MyPubsubEvent>(_mockEvent);

  //but the following does work.
      mockEvent.Setup( p =>
      p.Subscribe( It.IsAny<Action<string>>(),
      It.IsAny<ThreadOption>(),
      It.IsAny<bool>(),
      It.IsAny<Predicate<string>>()))
        .Callback<Action<string>, ThreadOption, bool, Predicate<string>>((e, t, b, a) => callback = e);
      return callback;
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
  callback.Invoke("someString");
  Assert.AreEqual("someString", SUT.StringProperty);
}
```

All I can think is that it's some kind of scoping issue, but not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Why do you want to mock `IEventAggregator` at all? You habe a tested version that you can trust to work (you do in your production code) in the library... also, _if_ you want to mock it, why use moq? Technically, you're allowed to use regular classes as mocks, too. Here, the mock will look very similar to the production version, though.

Comment: I'm using Moq mostly for the verify calls.  Primarily I want to verify that my subscriptions on the front end are subscribed to return on the UI thread, but I also want to make sure that my publishes are only called once in areas of code which call publish.